# Setting Verbosity to Verbose in psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

How do I set the setting value VERBOSE in psycopg2

This is the equivalent command in postgreSQL

```
\set VERBOSITY verbose
```

Comment: This seems not possible as of now in psycopg2 , it seems. Possibly need to request for this feature in psycopg2.

Answer (score 1):

According to the postgres [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES) `VERBOSITY` is used to

> control the verbosity of error reports.

Given that the name similarity and the fact that they take the same parameters I'm assuming the runtime config equivalent is `log_error_verbosity` whose documentation can be found in [runtime config logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html).

That being set you can use psycopg2 to execute the following SQL.

`set log_error_verbosity ='default';`

or

`set log_error_verbosity ='verbose';`

or

`set log_error_verbosity ='terse';`

And then to view the setting again use:

`show log_error_verbosity;`

Keep in mind that since this is a runtime config change the verbosity will only be changed during the session and will be reset to the default configuration upon session restart.